# Cakephp $this->log

Tags: cakephp

I would like to understand the meaning of

```
$this->log($user,'debug')
```

and

```
$this->log('index','debug')
```

in the following piece of code in CakePHP.
Thanks.

```
Class CompaniesController extends AppController
{
public function isAuthorized($user)
{
$this->log($user,'debug');

$action=$this->request->params['action'];

if(in_array($action,['index','category'])&& $this->isLoggedIn()){
$this->log('index','debug');
return true;
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is related to logging in Cakephp.

`$this->log` is used to logging/writing messages in the /logs/error.log file.

```
$this->log($user,'debug');
```

Here **debug** is logging level. This line will write `$user` variable data in /logs/error.log file.

And

```
$this->log('index','debug');
```

This will write "index" in /logs/error.log file.

CakePHP supports the standard POSIX set of logging levels. Each level represents an increasing level of severity:

```
Emergency: system is unusable
Alert: action must be taken immediately
Critical: critical conditions
Error: error conditions
Warning: warning conditions
Notice: normal but significant condition
Info: informational messages
Debug: debug-level messages
```

Reference: [Cakephp Logging](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/logging.html#writing-to-logs)

Comment: Thank you @Sehdev, could you please explain why we need to write the $user variable and index in logs/error file? Which effect does this have on the code execution, say on other parts of the code?

Comment: This is just to check the value of $user variable in error.log file instead of writing it on the page. Similarly to test if Current action is index or category and user is logged in index is written in  in the error.log file. You can write anything instead of "index" using $this->log();